# Powerapps model driven app, join 2 tables in the same view

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven

Hello I'm making aModel Driven App in powerapps. I have 2 tables **Question** and **Response**

The **Reponse** table have a lookup variable 'Question' with a Many-to-One relation (Response: N--1 : Question)

I want to make a seperate view that contains all the **questions** and **responses** together at the same time from my 2 seperate tables

How can I do that in model driven app please?

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible when you use Editable grid with Nested table option.

[Read more](https://d365goddess.com/nested-grids-in-dynamics-365/)

[image]